# Puppeteer script on DigitalOcean droplet running 24/7 maxes out memory and crashes

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer, digital-ocean

I have a simple puppeteer script that I leave running on a $5/month digitalocean droplet.  The script is below.  The script logins into an ecommerce website, and constantly refreshes the page look for a specific deal (if found adds to cart and checkouts).  As you can see from the monitoring graphs, the memory increases with every loop until it reaches max, and then crashes the script.  I think memory here is RAM, not storage.

Can anyone please suggest a better way to configure the puppeteer script to fix this problem? The loop takes about 5 seconds to run, and runs for about 12 hours until the memory usage increases to the point where the loop runtime creeps up from 5 seconds per run to 30 seconds per run.  Then eventually the memory reaches max and crashes the script.

Would closing and reopening the browser within each run fix the memory problem?
Is it because I have the script running as a never ending .js file?

Screenshot of Droplet memory

[image]

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer-extra')
puppeteer.use(require('puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth')())
const fs = require('fs');
const performance = require('perf_hooks').performance;


(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    args: ['--no-sandbox'],
    headless: true
  })
  const page = await browser.newPage()
 
  //Login to page
  await page.goto('https://example.com/login', {waitUntil: 'load', timeout: 0});
  await page.type('[name=email]','xxx@xxx.com');
  await page.click('button[type="submit"]');
  await page.waitForTimeout('input[name=password]');
  await page.type('[name=password]','xxx');
  await page.click('button[type="submit"]');

  var runcount = 0
  var foundcount = 0

  //loops always running after logging in
  while(true){
    var t0 = performance.now();  
    
    await page.goto('https://www.example.com/xxx', {waitUntil: 'load', timeout: 0});
    
    //do some await page.$$eval here
    
  
    runcount++;
    var t1 = performance.now();
    console.log("Run: " + runcount + " | Runtime: " + Math.floor((t1 - t0)/1000);
  
  }
 
  await browser.close()
})()
```

Comment: I would say it's because your page grows and grows without ever being "released" I dont really know how pupeteer works but i would create a new page in the while loop and release it at the end. Either way browser is allocating memory or the page is and never releasing it.

Comment: Instead of running the script continuously, I would suggest running it periodically say every ten minutes using a Cron job. Keeping a PuppeteerJS browser session running for that long is destined to end badly as it consumes a lot of memory. And since the page does not close there is no way memory is released anytime during that period which causes your RAM usage to reach peak levels.

Comment: Thank you but for this script, it needs to run quickly and continuously so 10 minutes is not an option.

Comment: Just for testing, you can try [`browser.createIncognitoBrowserContext()`](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/api.md#browsercreateincognitobrowsercontext) and [`browserContext.close()`](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/api.md#browsercontextclose) periodically — if the culprit is some history/cookies/cache growth, this can alleviate the issue.

Comment: Also, you can try [`page.setRequestInterception()`](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/api.md#pagesetrequestinterceptionvalue) and block any unneeded resources. Though you load the same page, it can use heavy ads from various sources, and this can impact the history/cookies/cache/sessions, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puppeteer works encapsulated with [PM2](https://pm2.keymetrics.io/) - is a javascript library that helps on watching node.js scripts - restarting the script when throws errors, etc. The encapsulation could be helpful for your case since there's a configuration for the memory threshold that restarts the entire script when reaches the limit specified, having a minimum downtime. It's super easy to use pm2, you only need to install the library, globally or locally, and then indicates the js file to load.

The library has good [documentation](https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/pm2-doc-single-page/) for your personal use.

After installed, you need to create an ecosystemfile.js in your project, like these, I have 2 different scripts, but you can put only one

```
module.exports = {
  apps : [{
    name: "server-centrodonto",
    script: "./dist/server.js",
    exp_backoff_restart_delay: 100,
    max_memory_restart: '200M',
    watch: false, 
    exec_mode  : "cluster",
    instances: 1,
    env: {
      "NODE_ENV": "development",
      "APP_NAME": "server-centrodonto",
      "PORT": 3030,
      "HOST": "localhost",
      "DATABASE": "centrodonto-database-development"
    },
    env_production : {
      "NODE_ENV": "production",
      "APP_NAME": "server-centrodonto",
      "PORT": 3030,
      "HOST": "localhost",
      "DATABASE": "centrodonto-database"
   }
  },
  {
    name: "wpp-bot-atendente_virtual-centrodonto", 
    // here you put your js file location
    script: "./dist/whatsappBot/AtendenteVirtual_bot.js",
    exp_backoff_restart_delay: 100,
    max_memory_restart: '200M',
    watch: false, 
    exec_mode  : "cluster",
    instances: 1,
    env: {
      "NODE_ENV": "development",
      "APP_NAME": "WPPbot_atendente virtual",
    },
    env_production : {
       "NODE_ENV": "production",
       "APP_NAME": "WPPbot_atendente virtual",
    }
  }
],

};
```

After you need to configure your package scripts like these:

```
 "scripts": {
    "start": "yarn pm2 start ecosystem.config.js --env production",
    "start-dev": "yarn pm2 start ecosystem.config.js"
  },
```

In my case, I have installed it locally.

After that just run yarn start, and the library will load your script. Then you can see the logs, and memory usage using commands: pm2 logs or pm2 monit

Comment: Thank you very much! PM2 is exactly what I needed and solved all my problems.